# Comparing sheets across two .xlsx files in python

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl, md5, xlsx

I am trying to compare two Excel (.xlsx) files and look to optimize my comparison. My file has around 1000 rows x 1000 columns and the time taken to compare each cell across two workbook is too long. So I decide to come up with a step-by-step approach.

1. Compare workbook using MD5 checksum - if matching, no further comparison needed
2. Compare each sheet across workbooks (if matching, no further comparison needed)
3. Compare each cell across sheets (only when point no. 2 results in difference)

I have the logic for point 1 and point 3 - I am looking for some help for a quick and smart way to compare sheets in point no 2. I am using openpyxl for .xlsx comparison

Any ideas welcomed to quickly perform comparison of xlsx - sheets across workbooks?

Comment: With this ***Compare workbook using MD5 checksum - if matching, no further comparison needed*** If two workbooks/sheets are being updated separately with the same data will the workbooks be exactly the same and therefore have the same checksum?